# element.remove doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a directive to remove elements from page depending on the user role.

Here's my **directive** :

```
angular.module("BlurAdmin")
    .directive('restrict',restrict);
function restrict (authService, $http, $state){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    prioriry: 100000,
    scope: false,
    link: function(){
    },
    compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
        var accessDenied = true;
        
        var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");
        
        var getCurrentUser = function () {

               authService.getCurrentUser()
                    .success(function (data) {
                        var user = data;
                        for(var i in attributes){
                          if(user.roles[0].name == attributes[i]){
                              accessDenied = false;
                          }
                        };
                        if(accessDenied){
                            element.children().remove();
                            element.remove();
                        };
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status) {
                        $state.go("/login");
                    });
        };
        getCurrentUser();
    }

  }
}
```

here's how I access it :

```
<input type="text" id="title" ng-model="reunion.title" restrict access="SUPERCHEF" required>
```

Everything works Ok but `element.remove`, it doesn't seem to be doing what it's supposed to be doing.

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

**EDIT :** When I do `element.text()` I'm getting the text inside my element but the element still doesn't get removed.

**BTW** I'm using this [front-end framework](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin)

**EDIT 2 :**
***WEIRD BEHAVIOUR***

If I remove the $http call and do it like this :

```
angular.module("BlurAdmin")
    .directive('restrict',restrict);

function restrict (authService, $http, $state){


return{
    restrict: 'A',
    prioriry: 100000,
    scope: true,
    link: function(){
        // alert('ergo sum!');
    },
    compile:  function(element, attr, linker){
        var accessDenied = true;
        
        var attributes = attr.access.split(" ");
        
        console.log("remove elem");
        element.children().remove();
       element.remove();
    }

  }
}
```

**--------->** The ELEMENTS ARE GETTING REMOVED.

but when I add the $http call the elements doesn't get removed.

Comment: this seems to work fine https://plnkr.co/edit/rJUPzdwNnnkP0a7lVkL9?p=preview. are you sure code is going into the if block where element is removed.

Comment: yeah I'm sure I tried it

Comment: maybe a scope problem ?

Comment: Just for testing, could you do the same in the link function instead of compile?

Comment: I just did and the directive doesn't even get called

Comment: And I verified it's not a scope problem as I'm getting the element in my directive

Comment: @Oddkills will it be possible for you to replicate this in a fiddle/plunker ?

Comment: well it's the same as what you did your plunker, I ain't doing nothing more

Comment: but there's one thing as the view I'm viewing is using a controller from a lower module than my directive, maybe that's the problem I don't know it's driving me crazy, I can't see anything wrong

Comment: is there any other solution the to remove an element?

Comment: check my last edit pls

Comment: @Oddkills - That kind of makes sense, your compile function will not wait for the ajax response and thats the reason why elements are not getting removed. By the time your ajax call completes, the compile function might have already done its job

Comment: but I tested it and the access denied variable is changing so the if condition validates and I can entrer the if statement

Comment: It sure will enter, but by the time the code in success event is executed, the directive would have got already compiled. You can do this by watching a variable; watch the variable in the directive controller and change the variable value in the success event. In the watch method, check the value and perform the element removal.

Comment: that's why I implemented the `element.remove` in the success $http call to get excuted after i get the roles, and yes I'm sure. I tried to use the `scope.$watch` but I can't seem to be able to inject the `scope` in `complie`